# Bayesian inference on Poisson rate parameter

Tags: bayesian, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

Given a Poisson arrival process of rate $\lambda$, and an observation of $k$ arrivals during an (arbitrary externally imposed) window of duration $t$, and prior p.d.f. $p(\lambda)$, is the following (unnormalized) posterior p.d.f. correct?

\begin{align}p(\lambda\mid t,k) 
   &= \frac{p(k\mid t,\lambda)p(t,\lambda)}{p(k,t)}\\ 
\\ &= \frac{p(k\mid t,\lambda)p(t\mid \lambda)p(\lambda)}{p(k,t)}\\
\\ &\propto_\lambda \frac{(\lambda t)^k}{k!}e^{-\lambda t}p(\lambda) 
\\ &\propto_\lambda \frac{t^k}{k!}\lambda^ke^{-\lambda t}p(\lambda) 
\\ &\propto_\lambda \lambda^ke^{-\lambda t}p(\lambda).
\end{align}

Comment: Can you be a bit more clear with your notation? I'm not really sure what $p(k,t)$ or $p(t,\lambda)$  would be here.

Comment: @Math1000 They are, respectively, the joint distribution of $k$ and $t$, and the joint distribution of $t$ and $\lambda$.

Comment: Okay, because you said that $t$ was "abitrarily externally imposed," i.e. that it is a constant. That was a little confusing.

Comment: @Math1000 Fixing $t$ allows me to drop the $p(t|\lambda)$, right? (Meaning that $p(t,\lambda)=p(\lambda)$)

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind here that conditioned on there being $k$ arrivals in an interval of length $t$, then those are uniformly distributed over that interval. But I wasn't sure how to use that.